# How can I adjust the width of the verse textblock with the dramatist package?

Tags: dramatist

I am trying to typeset a MacBeth edition for my English classes with additional commentaries. My main question is understanding how to influence the width of the verses - they are often a bit longer and then a linebreak occurs, which makes it look a bit chaotic.

See for example numbered verses 11, 23, 24 and more. The text is an excerpt from Scene 1-2.

I managed to move the speakers a bit to the left, see preamble code "setlength speaksskip". I'd like to expand the whole block a bit. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[paper=13cm:19cm,BCOR=4mm,10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[leftmargin=-6mm,rightmargin=-6mm,font={small,itshape},indentfirst=false]{quoting}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\frenchspacing
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000
\displaywidowpenalty = 10000
\pretolerance=10000

\KOMAoptions{DIV=18,parskip=off}

\setlength{\speaksskip}{-2em}

\title{MacBeth}
\author{William Shakespeare}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \poemlines{5}

    \Character[DUNCAN, King of Scotland]{Duncan}{dunc}

    \begin{CharacterGroup}{his sons}
        \GCharacter{MALCOLM}{Malcolm}{malco}    
        \GCharacter{DONALBAIN}{Donalbain}{dona}
    \end{CharacterGroup}

    \Character[Lords, Gentlemen, Officers, Soldiers, Murderers, Attendants, and Messengers; the Ghost of Banquo, and other Apparitions]{}{}
    \Character[]{Sergeant}{serg}


    \DramPer


\begin{drama*}

        \act

        \StageDir{A desert place}

        \scene


\begin{drama*}

    \duncspeaks
    What bloody man is that? He can report,\\
    As seemeth by his plight, of the revolt\\
    The newest state.\\
    \malcospeaks
    This is the sergeant\\
    Who like a good and hardy soldier fought\\
    'Gainst my captivity. Hail, brave friend!\\
    Say to the king the knowledge of the broil\footnote{broil = fight}\\
    As thou didst leave it.\\
    \sergspeaks
    Doubtful it stood;\\
    As two spent swimmers, that do cling together\\
    And choke their art. The merciless Macdonwald--\\
    Worthy to be a rebel, for to that\\
    The multiplying villanies of nature\\
    Do swarm upon him -- from the Western Isles\footnote{The Hebrides, a group of islands west of Scotland}\\
    Of kerns and gallowglasses\footnote{kerns = Celtic light-armored soldiers; gallowglasses = a form of mercenaries usually protecting Celtic chiefs} is supplied;\\
    And fortune, on his damned quarrel smiling,\\
    Show'd like a rebel's whore: but all's too weak:\\
    For brave Macbeth -- well he deserves that name--\\
    Disdaining fortune, with his brandish'd steel,\\
    Which smoked with bloody execution,\\
    Like valour's minion carved out his passage\\
    Till he faced the slave;\\
    Which ne'er shook hands, nor bade farewell to him,\\
    Till he unseam'd him from the nave to the chaps,\\
    And fix'd his head upon our battlements.\\
    \duncspeaks
    O valiant cousin! worthy gentleman!\\
    \sergspeaks
    As whence the sun 'gins his reflection\footnote{e.g.: From where the sun begins to rise; see also below "whence" = where, from where}\\
    Shipwrecking storms and direful thunders break,\\
    So from that spring whence comfort seem'd to come\\
    Discomfort swells. Mark, king of Scotland, mark:\\
    No sooner justice had with valour arm'd\\
    Compell'd these skipping kerns to trust their heels,\\
    But the Norweyan lord surveying vantage,\\
    With furbish'd arms and new supplies of men\\
    Began a fresh assault.\\

\end{drama*}

\end{drama*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setlength{\leftmargini}{1em}` should work. Btw: I do find it a bit curious that your write MacBeth in the title, but Macbeth in the text.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Presumably the title is a new one coined by the OP for this edition, whereas the text is the original by Shakespeare. A bit like *Collected Works of Shakespeare*, but without the collecting.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for both. Sloppyness - bad attitude. It's not a for-profit edition, just something for and with my students so they can enjoy studying Shakespeare and have something to keep and remember at the end.